# make enumerated button in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

Is it possible to make an enumerated button, similar to the ones shown in the figure below? I will be using them as pictures in an external document (not TeX).

[image]

Comment: Yes it is possible. How far are you? Can you post your code, so it can be used as a starting point for those who wish to help you? What conceptual problems do you have?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Another approach:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz,x11names]{standalone}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[button/.style 2 args={
 circle, 
 minimum size=0.75cm,
 top color=#1!30!white,
 bottom color=#1,
 draw=#1!90!black,
 thick,
 append after command={
  node[circle,draw=#1!90!white,
   minimum size=0.68cm,
   font=\sffamily]at(\tikzlastnode.center)
   {\textcolor{white}{\contour{#1}{#2}}}
 },
 general shadow={
  shadow xshift=.2ex, shadow yshift=-.2ex,
opacity=.5, fill=black!50,
 }
 }]

\foreach \buttoncolor[count=\i] in {red, DarkOrange1,Goldenrod1,Green3,blue!50!cyan,DarkOrchid2}
\node[button={\buttoncolor}{\i}] at (\i, 0){};

\foreach \buttoncolor[count=\xi,evaluate=\xi as \i using int(13-\xi)] in {Azure2,gray!25!white,Snow3,Snow4,black!80!white,black}
\node[button={\buttoncolor}{\i}] at (\xi, -1){};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Very beautiful!

Comment: I agree with Uwe. It's really beautiful.

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[lining]{libertine}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\begin{document}
\foreach \x/\Color in {1/red,2/red!50,3/orange,4/blue!50!green,5/blue}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[gray!20] (0.02,-0.03) circle (0.5cm);
    \node[circle,minimum width=1cm,text=white,fill=\Color,font=\sffamily] at (0,0) {\x};
    \draw[line width = 0.2pt,white!50!black] (0,0) circle (0.475cm);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\foreach \x/\Color in {11/black!20,12/black!40,13/black!60,14/black!80,15/black}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[gray!20] (0.02,-0.03) circle (0.5cm);
    \node[circle,minimum width=1cm,text=white,fill=\Color,font=\sffamily] at (0,0) {\x};
    \draw[line width = 0.2pt,white!50!black] (0,0) circle (0.475cm);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]