# How can I annotate a figure with lines and circled numbers

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, circles

I want to replace static image annotations with annotations in LaTeX to have them be all the same size. I always use figures and sometimes subfigures.

How would I get the same lines as in the image with numbers as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7045/50965 ? Can I resuse that circled code?

[image: annotated image]

I tried and searched for some tikz solutions but am not familiar with how I would approach this.

The code of this specific image (in a sub figure) is:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{figure}[tph]
\hspace{5mm}\subfloat[figure 1 description]{%
\begin{minipage}[b][1\totalheight][c]{0.4\columnwidth}%
\noindent \begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=1\columnwidth]{path/To/Image}
\par\end{center}%
\end{minipage}



}\hfill{}\subfloat[mentioned figure from question]{\noindent \begin{centering}
\begin{minipage}[b][5.5cm][c]{0.4\columnwidth}%
\noindent \begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=1\columnwidth]{path/To/Image}
\par\end{center}%
\end{minipage}
\par\end{centering}



}\hspace{5mm}

\protect\caption{de}


\end{figure}
```

Comment: For fancy circles, you may want to see [make enumerated button in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/167013/13304).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is very easy and may be a duplicate too. Any way, I am posting this and if this is closed a duplicate, I will delete this answer.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0,0) {\includegraphics[width=4in]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        %% next four lines will help you to locate the point needed by forming a grid. comment these four lines in the final picture.↓
  %      \draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
%        \draw[help lines,xstep=.05,ystep=.05] (0,0) grid (1,1);
%        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
%        \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y};}
        %% upto here↑
        \draw[dashed,-latex] (0.8,0.8) -- +(1.1in,0.2in)node[anchor=west] {1};
        \draw[dashed,-latex] (0.6,0.6) -- +(1.9in,0)node[anchor=west] {2};
        \draw[dashed,-latex] (0.4,0.5) -- +(-2in,0)node[anchor=east] {3};
        \draw[dashed,-latex] (0.5,0.4) -- +(-2.4in,-0.5in)node[anchor=east] {4};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can use this inside regular `fu=igure`s/`subfigure`s like this. I have modified the `minipage` dimensions. Roll it back in your case. Also, it is better to use `\centering` than `\begin{center}... \end{center}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{mynode/.style={draw,solid,circle,inner sep=1pt}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[tph]
\subfloat[figure 1 description]{%
\begin{minipage}{0.4\columnwidth}%
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \draw[dashed,-latex] (0.8,0.8) -- +(1.1cm,0.2cm)node[mynode,anchor=west] {1};
        \draw[dashed,-latex] (0.6,0.6) -- +(1.9cm,0)node[mynode,anchor=west] {2};
        \draw[dashed,-latex] (0.4,0.5) -- +(-2cm,0)node[mynode,anchor=east] {3};
        \draw[dashed,-latex] (0.5,0.4) -- +(-2.4cm,-0.5cm)node[mynode,anchor=east] {4};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
}\hfill{}
\subfloat[mentioned figure from question]{
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.4\columnwidth}%
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image-B}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \draw[dashed,-latex] (0.8,0.8) -- +(1.1cm,0.2cm)node[mynode,anchor=west] {1};
        \draw[dashed,-latex] (0.6,0.6) -- +(1.9cm,0)node[mynode,anchor=west] {2};
        \draw[dashed,-latex] (0.4,0.5) -- +(-2cm,0)node[mynode,anchor=east] {3};
        \draw[dashed,-latex] (0.5,0.4) -- +(-2.4cm,-0.5cm)node[mynode,anchor=east] {4};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
}
\caption{de}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can define a `style` for the `node` like

```
\tikzset{mynode/.style={draw,solid,circle,inner sep=1pt}}
```

and use it like

```
\draw[dashed,-latex] (0.8,0.8) -- +(1.1cm,0.2cm)node[mynode,anchor=west] {1};
```

### **addendum from @Hug:**

the answer helped very much, but I wanted to also show the complete answer to get a desired result which also has the happy side effects of:

- image scale agnosticism (through relative positions, not cm)
- white filled circled numbers, so one can put them inside a figure (achieved through style options)
- use of styles to easily color the lines according to a color scheme (I used Adobe kuler web app for a custom color scheme for me)
- no arrow endings of the lines (no -latex option)

this results in the following MWE (with 8 different colors to choose from):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz}
%colors
\definecolor{1c1}{RGB}{188,162,6}
\definecolor{1c2}{RGB}{137,129,80}
\definecolor{1c3}{RGB}{239,167,31}
\definecolor{1c4}{RGB}{88,194,241}
\definecolor{1c5}{RGB}{6,180,188}

% stiles used
\tikzset{mynode/.style={draw=black,solid,circle,fill=white,inner sep=2pt, thick, text=black}}
%draw=black to get a black circle, fill=white so it actually has a   
%background and text=black to not get that rendered in the specified color
\tikzset{arrow line/.style={dashed, line width= 2.5pt, color=#1}}
%color is given as a paramter so one can put these two styles in the  
%preamble and easily use throughout the document, line width as it was to small on my images on a page

\begin{figure}[tbph]
\hspace{5mm}\subfloat[figure a]{%
\begin{minipage}[b][1\totalheight][c]{0.4\columnwidth}%
\noindent \begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=1\columnwidth]{path/to/image_a}
\par\end{center}%
\end{minipage}



}\hfill{}\subfloat[description of figure a]{\noindent \centering%
\begin{minipage}[b][5cm][c]{0.4\columnwidth}%
\noindent \begin{center}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.7\columnwidth]{path/to/image}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
% uncomment the 4 lines for a grid to help with positioning
        % \draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
        % \draw[help lines,xstep=.05,ystep=.05] (0,0) grid (1,1);
        % \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
        % \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y};}

% uncomment until line above
        \draw[arrow line=1c1] (0.8,0.8) -- +(0.275,0)node[mynode,anchor=west] {\Large 1};
%1c1 is the code for the color, you can enter 1c2 here, too
        \draw[arrow line=1c1] (0.6,0.55) -- +(0.475,0)node[mynode,anchor=west] {\Large 2};
        \draw[arrow line=1c1] (0.35,0.45) -- +(-0.425,0)node[mynode,anchor=east] {\Large 3};
        \draw[arrow line=1c1] (0.375,0.275) -- +(-0.45,-.15)node[mynode,anchor=east] {\Large 4};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\par\end{center}%
\end{minipage}

}\hspace{5mm}

\protect\caption{outside caption}


\end{figure}
```

which results in this image:

[image: final resulting image]

So, thanks a lot to  Harish Kumar, without whose help this hadn't been possible for me.

Comment: thank you, but how can I use your code in my "begin figure" code? I still want to use regular figures. Can i use tikzpicture inside my figure itself?

Comment: @Hug I have updated the answer.

Comment: Hi, after fiddling with your answer and looking in the documentation of pgf, I came up with a complete solution including the use of custom color scheme (I use kuler for the color schemes). Are you fine with me adding the specific solution on the very bottom of your answer and commenting it and then answering your answer as the solution?

Comment: PS: Why is the use of \centering more advisable than the use of \begin{center}...?

Comment: @Hug: Feel free. `\begin{center}` adds extra vertical space where as `\centering` doesn't. Some times, especially in figures and tables, this extra space is unwanted. Hence the suggestion.

Comment: thx for the clarification. Do you know how this "peer reviewing" process of edited answers works?

Comment: @Hug: For low reputation users, the edits will go through a review process. I have approved your edit as such. :-)

Comment: hope the addendum helps ;-)

Comment: @Hug I know this is an old post but what if our picture is rectangular ? Then when we use commands such as `\draw[] (0.5,0.5) circle (0.1)`, the circle is not a circle. How can we avoid this and make a square grid for example?

Comment: I will have a look hopefully later today. I never ran into that problem, but I don't know how I did and am not near my computer.

Comment: Hi @mwoua, I just had a look but I don't know why you would use \draw[] in this context. My solution (and it works for me with pictures of any shape) defines a node that you reuse. The circles are still circles in my case. Did you try copy and pasting my solution and then changing it to accomodate your needs?

Comment: Hi @Hug, thank you for your answer. I use 
`\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{NuclideMap2.png}};
\begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
\draw[thick] (0.075,0.075) circle (0.075);`
in the picture [here](http://imgur.com/a/GEzJk) . As you can see, the circle is not really a circle. Sorry for the format, I cannot go to the line after each line of code.

Comment: Did you put it into a tikzpicture? When I just wanted circles, I was able to have a line of length 0 (same coordinates) and you can get the circle transparent by modifying the style. But as I said: Did you try literally copy and pasting the code above and modifying it to your needs?