# Draw Circle About Figure

Tags: floats, draw

I have a figure and would like to highlight a particular region of that figure with a circle or an ellipse as shown in figure:

[image]

It is important that the line of the circle or ellipse are thick. How do I control the location of the circle, to up, down, right or left?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198492/how-can-i-annotate-a-figure-with-lines-and-circled-numbers help?

Comment: Or this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(a){\includegraphics{circle.png}};
\node at(a.center)[draw, red,line width=3pt,ellipse, minimum width=118pt, minimum height=50pt,rotate=-28,yshift=-48pt]{};
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used red so that you can see where my ellipse is with respect to the original ellipse. You can fine-tune the positioning via shifts, `rotate`, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a way by using `\tikz` for the ellipse, and then `\stackinset` to overlay it on the image.  Arguments #2 and #4 to `\stackinset` are the offsets from the `l`eft, `b`ottom of the image (horizontal offsets can be with respect to `l`, `c`, or `r` and vertical `t`, `c`, or `b`), while the 4 arguments to `\solidcirc` are the rotation angle, line thickness, and the x and y radii of the ellipse.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,tikz,graphicx}
\newcommand\solidcirc[4][0]{\rotatebox{#1}{\tikz{\draw[line width=#2] (0,0) 
  arc [x radius=#3,y radius=#4,start angle=0,end angle=360];}}}
\begin{document}
\stackinset{l}{1in}{b}{.8in}{\textcolor{blue}{\solidcirc[-30]{3pt}{2.8}{1.0}}}
  {\includegraphics{example-image}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to draw more than one ellipse in the same figure? For example, a blue ellipse and a red ellipse.

Comment: @WendellFialho Yes. You can nest them, wherein the first inset becomes argument `#6` of the outer inset.  If you do *many* insets at once, it renders more quickly if you save intermediate results in a box, and use the box as argument `#6`.  The `\savestack` mechanism utilizes this boxed mechanism.  E.g. `\savestack\inbox{\stackinset{}{}{}{}{}{}}`. Then, `\stackinset{}{}{}{}{}{\inbox}`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. But I did not understand the practice of how this command works to insert multiple ellipses. You can kindly demonstrate it through an example image.

Comment: @WendellFialho This, answer, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171483/mathematical-formulas-on-a-graph-not-made-by-tex/171486#171486, shows nested `\stackinset`s... 5 insets over the base image.

Comment: @WendellFialho `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,tikz}
\newcommand\solidcirc[4][0]{\rotatebox{#1}{\tikz{\draw[line width=#2] (0,0) 
  arc [x radius=#3,y radius=#4,start angle=0,end angle=360];}}}
\begin{document}
\stackinset{l}{.5in}{b}{.3in}{\textcolor{red}{\solidcirc[30]{3pt}{2.4}{1.0}}}{\stackinset{l}{1in}{b}{.8in}{\textcolor{blue}{\solidcirc[-30]{3pt}{2.8}{1.0}}}{\includegraphics{example-image}}}
\end{document}`

Comment: I am trying to apply this method to make 3 circles and even more occasions (e.g. 3, 4, 5 ...) circles. In an attempt to make the third circle and following your example I did it according to the following code, however, I was not successful:

Comment: \documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{stackengine,tikz} 
\newcommand\solidcirc[4][0]{\rotatebox{#1}{\tikz{\draw[line width=#2] (0,0) arc [x radius=#3,y radius=#4,start angle=0,end angle=360];}}} 

\begin{document} \stackinset{l}{.5in}{b}{.3in}{\textcolor{red}{\solidcirc[30]{3pt}{2.4}{1.0}}}{\stackinset{l}{1in}{b}{.8in}{\textcolor{blue}{\solidcirc[-30]{3pt}{2.8}{1.0}}}{\stackinset{l}{1in}{b}{.8in}{\textcolor{green}{\solidcirc[-30]{3pt}{2.8}{1.0}}}{\includegraphics{example-image}}}
 \end{document}

Comment: @WendellFialho `\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{stackengine,tikz} 
\newcommand\solidcirc[4][0]{\rotatebox{#1}{\tikz{\draw[line width=#2] (0,0) 
  arc [x radius=#3,y radius=#4,start angle=0,end angle=360];}}} 
\begin{document} 
\stackinset{l}{.5in}{b}{.3in}{\textcolor{red}{\solidcirc[30]{3pt}{2.4}{1.0}}}
  {\stackinset{l}{1in}{b}{.8in}{\textcolor{blue}{\solidcirc[-30]{3pt}{2.8}{1.0}}}
  {\stackinset{l}{1.4in}{b}{.8in}{\textcolor{green}{\solidcirc[-30]{3pt}{2.8}{1.0}}}
  {\includegraphics{example-image}}}}
\end{document}`